# Switching between multiple XAML files

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic

I am making a video game and at this level, I am trying to make it run with multiple resolution options.

For every possible resolution that will be available in my game, I made a separate xaml file, with different heights, widths, margins, font sizes, but same attachments to code.

Now, I want to allow user to choose resolutions, and hence for every such choice, load a xaml file.

For example at the start of the game, I want the app to check which resolution is now active.

I really can't provide some specific code here, I don't know how to do it. I tried adding xaml files as resources, but still don't understand how to choose one of them as active.

Something like:

```
if (Resolution=="1600x900")
{
// make resource file "res_1600_900.xaml" be active instead of MainWindow.xaml
}
```

Of course, I can just assign the code to files in the folder and not resources, it doesn't matter.

And if there is another way to change all sizes and positions of all objects at once, I'll be glad to hear it.

Thank you,
Evgenie

UPD: My error messages after copying xaml to UserControl

> Error 4   'RealityIncognita.UserControl1' does not contain a definition for 'AnySoundEnd' and no extension method 'AnySoundEnd' accepting a first argument of type 'RealityIncognita.UserControl1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Evgenie\Desktop\Quest game\RealityIncognita_0.7.4\RealityIncognita\res_1600_900.xaml   25  114 RealityIncognita

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easiest way to solve this:

1. Create your main window with everything sized to the most commonly used resolution.
2. Use `x:Name` to name any controls whos margins, fonts, sizes, or whatever will need to change when the resolution is changed.

`<Button x:Name="RedButton" Margin="0,0,0,4" Content="Fire" Click="RB_Click"/>`

3. In code behind, when the user changes the resolution, update the sizes for things:

   `RedButton.Margin = new Thickness(10,10,10,40);`
4. Do the above or similar to all controls that need resized and they will be immediately resized.

Another way to solve this (which is the one you appear to have started):

1. Create a separate user control for each resolution you plan on supporting. (let's call them UC1, UC2, UC3, UC4 for simplicity here)
2. Assign one of them to a window that you're displaying to the user:

   myWindow.Child = UC1;
3. If/when the user changes the resolution, just change the user control that is appearing in the window:

   myWindow.Child = UC3;

It looks like you may be working inside of the main window code-bahind.  If this is the case, replace the above lines of code with this:

```
Child = UC1;
```

or

```
Child = UC3;
```

Name them something easy like UC

Comment: Can you please explain it more, or link where I can find example code? I am still new to this, so don't know how to implement what you said.

Comment: Sorry for all those questions, but I still don't understand. After I create the UserControl, I am to copy xaml code there, right? But I get error messages - I think they are about my voids. I'll update my first post with example. Can I somehow cancel all of them rather then deleting one by one?

Comment: As for the alternative, manually changing sizes and margins, that's what I tried in the first place. The problem is I have hundreds of objects and its hard to do it manually, while trying to automate it leads to bugs.